# Which .sh will run first: base image or the .sh present in the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

Suppose I have a base image:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
.
.
COPY ./temp1.sh /sbin/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["start-service"]
```

I called the image on my Dockerfile

```
FROM letsdoit/baseimage
.
.
COPY ./temp2.sh /sbin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["start-service"]
```

So what will be the order of execution?

Answer (score 1):

Your settings for ENTRYPOINT and CMD overwrite the ones of the base image. This means the base script will not run at all.

Furthermore, you even have overwritten the `/sbin/entrypoint.sh` file with your own version. So the original script is not even available in the file system of the container.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch the image, unless you change settings on the `docker run` command, it will run (only) `/sbin/entrypoint.sh`, and that will receive a single command-line argument `start-service`.

The CMD and ENTRYPOINT in the derived image totally overwrite the corresponding settings in the base image.  A container only runs one command and that’s the most recent ENTRYPOINT (or the `docker run --entrypoint` if you manually set that).